# how do I get the EXACT number of months between two dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, monthcalendar

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1/1/2014', '12/31/2014') + 1
```

This will give me 12.

What if I do this:

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1/1/2014', '12/30/2014') + 1
```

It should give me 11 point something. How do I go about getting the exact number of months between these two dates? This needs to work for any combination of dates (any month of the year for any year).

Comment: By exact, do you mean full months? and how many months between 31/1/2014 -> 1/2/2014? and 31/1/2014 -> 28/2/2014?

Comment: Full or not depending on the input parameters. I need the exact number of months between two dates, taking into account that the number might be a decimal. In my example, the difference is 11 POINT something months, NOT 12 whole months.

Comment: you're adding one to the result (11) 11+1 = 12.    `SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1/1/2014', '12/31/2014')` and `SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1/1/2014', '12/30/2014')` both return 11

Comment: DATEDIFF is built to return the number of date BOUNDARIES that are crossed. This is in the manual. Also, "month" is an arbitrary concept when applied to a certain number of days in an interval. For example, all of February and all of March is usually only 59 days, but all of July and August is 62.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the calculation yourself in the following way:

```
DECLARE @startdate date = '1/1/2014'
DECLARE @enddate date = '12/30/2014'

DECLARE @startday int = DATEPART(DAY, @startdate)
DECLARE @endday int = DATEPART(DAY, @enddate)
DECLARE @startdateBase date = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - @startday, @startdate)
DECLARE @enddateBase date = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - @endday, @enddate)

DECLARE @deciMonthDiff float = CAST(DATEDIFF(MONTH, @startdate, @enddate) AS float) -
  (@startday - 1.0) / DATEDIFF(DAY, @startdateBase, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @startdateBase)) +
  (@endday - 1.0) / DATEDIFF(DAY, @enddateBase, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @enddateBase))

SELECT @deciMonthDiff
```

This calculates the `@deciMonthDiff` to be 11.935483870967.
Of course you can "inline" this as much as you want in order to avoid all the middle declarations.

The idea is to calculate the total month diff, then subtract the relative part of the first & last month depending on the actual day.

Answer (score 2):

DATEDIFF with the MONTH option only returns an integer value. Using days or years would give you a rough "guesstimate" but still not exactly right (different number of days in a month/year so you can't just divide the days difference by 30).

If you want exact you would need to write your own function to walk through the months from start until end and account for how many days are in each month and get a percentage/factor of that month covered.

Comment: You don't have to "walk all months", you only need to correct for first & last, and it's not that horrible to do

Comment: True enough I suppose. It is all the same logic to know what percentage of a month you are "consuming" so I am not sure it would be much difference in the work required.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @startdate date = '1/1/2014'
DECLARE @enddate date = '12/30/2014'

select  case when  DATEPART(DAY, @startdate) <=  DATEPART(DAY, @enddate) 
    then datediff(month, @startdate, @enddate)  
    else datediff(month, @startdate, @enddate) -1  
    end
```

from Chris The Jedi of T-SQL

Comment: if startdate is 20200202 and enddate is 20200201,
this give -1 even just one day different!!